# How to set a background to a listview item on click and change dynamically on other clicks

Tags: android, listview

hi i am having a list view and on click i want to show a background image to the selected list item, and change the background if the selection is changed. i had been trying to implement this but was not able to do so. please help me with this and would be grateful so

please find the code i am using

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final int getstartedItemPos = position;
        Resources res = getResources();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.getting_starteditem, null);
        }
        synchronized (view) {
            TextView textTopic = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.indexItems);
            textTopic.setText(getStartedItems[getstartedItemPos]);
            textTopic.setTypeface(tf);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        }
        return view;
    }

};

private OnItemClickListener getStartedListItem = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent myintent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),GetStartedWebview.class);
         myintent.putExtra("SelectedItem", getStartedItems[position]);
         startActivity(myintent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see from your code if you have attached the `OnItemClickListener` to your ListView, you should do that if you haven't. In `onItemClick` you can grab the View that is clicked (arg1) and use `.setBackgroundResource(int resID)` on it to change it's background

**EDIT:** You can use a local variable that holds the current List item showing the background, so do something like:

```
private View pressedView = null; 

private OnItemClickListener getStartedListItem = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent myintent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),GetStartedWebview.class);
         myintent.putExtra("SelectedItem", getStartedItems[position]);
         startActivity(myintent);

         if(pressedView != null) {
             pressedView.setBackgroundResource(..); // reset background of old item
             pressedView = arg1; // Point pressedView to new item
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks soren, i did that but the problem is the background does not change if i click other items, the background is set to all items that are clicked instead it should only be one item

Comment: i did the same way as  u have said but still it does not work, the background does not change... please help

Answer (score 4):

Try this in listview:-

```
android:listSelector="@color/orange"
```

Answer (score 3):

pinkcandy use this, `View lastView;`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long arg3) 
    {


        if(lastView==null){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            lastView=v;
            }
            else{
            lastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
             v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            lastView=v;
            }

    }
```

it may help you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but if i understand you right you have to set background of your view only once, but it should be *selector* drawable, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="*background for pressed state*" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="*background for focused state*" />
    <item
        android:drawable="*default background*" />

</selector>
```